# open 2 adodb connections in php

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

I want to open 2 adodb connection. I wrote this code but it does not work. Is there any way to solve it?

```
$conn1 = ADONewConnection('mysql');
$conn1->PConnect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname1);

$conn2 = ADONewConnection('mysql');
$conn2->PConnect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname2);
```

When I ran

```
$sqlreadrecord = "SELECT * FROM `1net`";
$recordSet = $conn1->Execute($sqlreadrecord);
```

it said errorTable 'abcd.1net' doesn't exist
it seems like it is searching for 1net table from $dbname2.

Comment: are you sure you get connected with database ?

Answer (score 0):

have looked at the documentation of adodb. seems you can connect to two different db servers / db at the same time. there is a sample in the link below.

http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#ex6

you might want to try:

```
$conn1 = &ADONewConnection('mysql');
$conn1->PConnect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname1);

$conn2 = &ADONewConnection('mysql');
$conn2->PConnect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname2);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you had your solution but here is help for other people.

I have the same problem; I try this

```
$conn1 = ADONewConnection('mysql');
$conn1->PConnect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname1);

$conn2 = ADONewConnection('mysql');
$conn2->NConnect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname2); //NConnect for the new connection
```

http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm

If you realize it is ok . check right for the other public. Thanks